# How to see all your accepted submissions on Slashdot?

Tags: slashdot

I've submitted a number of stories to Slashdot, and many of the later ones got accepted, some earlier ones not.

However, if I go into my profile, `/~example/submissions`, I only see the original submissions, not the actual final stories with lots of comments on them.

Is there a way to easily see your published stories in one place?